# Laplace Transformation for the Negative Binomial Distribution

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution

I am trying to do this using the Poisson-Gamma mixture parameterization.

I think the derivation is related to the derivation of the expected value. But I have only seen how to derive the mean using conditioning, not from summation. Could someone help?

Comment: Is your question that you're trying to prove that the neg binomial is a mixture of poison and Gamma?

Comment: No, I am trying to understand when negative binomial is set up as a mixture of Poisson/Gamma, how to derive its Laplace Transform?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285378/moment-generating-function-negative-binomial,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236728/negative-binomial-mgf-converges-to-poisson-mgf